# DB Error at Installation

Tags: error, installation

I have been runnning civiCRM for more than 2 years until now ; but I meet some problems (phone number cannot be saved).

So I try to install a new CiviCRM (4.7.11) on Drupal 7.50, the simplest way : install Drupal via Cpanel, upload civicrm tar.gz, and then install via sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php (fetching Data Base credentials inside settings.php).

I have made several trials (http or https, same or separate database(s)) : all of them end with a

> "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: unknown error".

However, all the civicrm tables are created, and the CiviCRM Menu can be displayed, but whatever I want to do (e.g. create a new contact), I get this DB Error again, and the info is not saved.

My hosting is based upon PHP 5.5, MariaDB 10.0.27 (supposed to be fully compatible with MySQL) (and a friend of mine, who uses the same hoster, has no such installation problem)

The significant error information is:

> DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, (array:2), "SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_numer...")

and

> DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1728 ** Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted")

A backtrace from when I try to create a new contact is shown below.

[image: backtrace]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please update the question by pasting the text from the screenshot into the question?  It's hard to read right now, and isn't searchable for others who might have the same question later!

Comment: Tank you Chris for editing my post : much better !

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found that this was due to a .htaccess jam (between drupal and civicrm) : inconsistencies and contradictions in "rewriterules", used to https:// the site, delete initial www., and redirect (and keep) to the pertinent civicrm directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. It's when the host upgrades mysql and system tables don't get upgraded. I had to ask them to run mysql_upgrade.

See also  http://www.myguysolutions.com/2013/10/30/how-to-resolve-mysql-error-code-1548-cannot-load-from-mysql-proc-the-table-is-probably-corrupted/

Comment: I already proposed that to my hoster : it is not the cause. I personally suspect a problem with .htaccess or settings.php vs https